# Elements are clipping with mouseover/out childs elements of a div

Tags: jquery, mouseover, mouseout

I wish to display some buttons inside a div while hovering it.

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Phhnh/2/)

// HTML

```
<div id="overdiv"> 
<p>Move your mouse several times on this text to see the bug</p> 
<input type="button" value="hello" class="elements"/> 
</div>
```

// CSS

```
#overdiv {background:#CCC;border:1px solid #FFF;width:300px;height:150px;}
.elements {display:none;}
```

// JS

```
$('#overdiv').mouseover(function(){$('.elements').fadeIn();}).mouseout(function(){$('.elements').fadeOut();});
```

It works, but while mouse hovers other elements inside the div then my button appears and disappears in loop. (I've only tested it with Chrome)

So, how to make the button appear once, while mouse is inside the div, and disappear once, while mouse is out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the "mouseover"-Event, use "mouseenter".

```
$('#overdiv').mouseenter(function(){$('.elements').fadeIn();}).mouseleave(function(){$('.elements').fadeOut();});
```

Explanation: "mouseover" and "mouseout" are triggered for every element and its children, so if you "mouseout" the text, your "mouseout" event is triggered...

Answer (score 1):

try this way to solve the problem.....

$('#overdiv').mouseenter(function(){$('.elements').fadeIn();});
$('#overdiv').mouseleave(function(){$('.elements').fadeOut();});